# Wordpress Multiple Custom Post Type filters with Custom Taxonomies using Ajax - all newly created posts do not show in response

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, filter, custom-taxonomy

Update: well, I answered my own question. Anyone who wants to help me add pagination to response, I’ll gladly buy you a pint of whatever works for you. :) some code needs to be cleaned up here. will do later.

—

I had about 45 posts in a custom post type named 'insights' and my filters were working fine. I moved the posts to a post type named 'insight' using CPT UI and everything seemed to still be working fine.  There are 5 custom taxonomies to use for an ajax filter grid. Now, any newly created posts will show in a WP query but will not return after the form action. So post 46 and 47, for example, don't show on filter, but all of the older posts do and are correctly filtering. I can't figure out what happened. I'm wondering if migrating the post type is the issue? Sharing the code I'm using below and grateful for any ... insight(s). This is my first question here, and I'm willing to pay for mentorship on this, if that's not against the policies. Thanks in advance for any help.

--In my functions.php

```
            global $wp_query;
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-pagination', 'ajaxpagination', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'query_vars' => json_encode( $wp_query->query )
));

require_once( get_template_directory() . '/library/functions/filter-scripts.php'); 
require_once( get_template_directory() . '/library/functions/ajax-filter-insights.php');
```

--/library/functions/filter-scripts.php

```
            <?php
/*
* Enqueue scripts.js if file scripts.js exists
*/
function load_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script('ajax', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/filter-scripts.js', array('jquery'), NULL, true);

    wp_localize_script('ajax' , 'wpAjax',
        array('ajaxUrl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'))
    );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts' );
```

--/assets/js/filter-scripts.js

```
(function ($) {

  $(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on('submit', '[data-js-form=filter]', function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();
      var data = $(this).serialize();

      $.ajax({
        url: wpAjax.ajaxUrl,
        data: data,
        type: 'post',
        success: function (result) {
          $('[data-js-filter=target]').html(result);
        },
        error: function (result) {
          console.warn(result);
        }
      });


    });
  });

})(jQuery);
```

--/library/functions/ajax-filter-insights.php

```
    <?php add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'misha_filter_function'); // wp_ajax_{ACTION HERE}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'misha_filter_function');

function misha_filter_function(){
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'insight',
        'post_status' => 'published'
    );



            if( isset( $_POST['all-services'] ) ) {
                $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'insight_service',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $_POST['insight-service']
                );

            }


            if( isset( $_POST['all-types'] ) ) {
                $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'insight_types',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $_POST['insight-types']
                );

            }
            if( isset( $_POST['all-topics'] ) ) {
                $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'insight_topics',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $_POST['insight-topics']
                );

            }
            if( isset( $_POST['all-months'] ) ) {
                $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'insight_months',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $_POST['insight-months']
                );

            }
            if( isset( $_POST['all-years'] ) ) {
                $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'insight_years',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $_POST['insight-years']
                );

            }

            if( isset( $_POST['insight-service'] ) ) {
                $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'insight_service',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $_POST['insight-service']
                );

            }


            if( isset( $_POST['insight-type'] ) ) {
                $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'insight_type',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $_POST['insight-type']
                );

            }


            if( isset( $_POST['insight-topic'] ) ) {
                $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'insight_topic',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $_POST['insight-topic']
                );

            }
            if( isset( $_POST['insight-month'] ) ) {
                $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'insight_month',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $_POST['insight-month']
                );

            }
            if( isset( $_POST['insight-year'] ) ) {
                $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'insight_year',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $_POST['insight-year']
                );

            }




            $query = new WP_Query( $args );

            if( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<style>
    .post-grid__col {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<div class="container-fluid post-grid p--normal">
    <div class="row my-3">
        <?php
                while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?>


        <div class="post-grid__col col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 m-0">
            <a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>">
                <div class="post-card h-100 animate__animated animate__fadeInUp">
                    <div class="post-card__thumb"
                        style="background: url(<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url();?>) no-repeat; background-size: 100%; background-position: center;">
                        <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/general/post-tax-term.php'); ?>

                    </div>
                    <p class="text--lightblue text-uppercase letter-spacing--261 font-53-ex"> <?php echo get_the_date();?>
                    </p>

                    <h2 class="post-card__title">
                        <?php echo the_title();?>
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </a>

        </div>
        <?php
                endwhile;

                wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>

        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="load-btn__wrapper d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <a href="#" id="loadMore" class="cta-btn">
                    <div class="cta-inner cta-inner--inverted d-flex align-items-center"><span
                            class="arrow_carrot-right text-white"></span><span class="btn-label">Show More</span></div>
                </a>

                <p class="totop">
                    <a href="#filter" class="no-transform">Back to top &#9650;</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            jQuery(function ($) {

                $(function () {
                    $(".post-grid__col").slice(0, 9).show();
                    $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $(".post-grid__col:hidden").slice(0, 9).fadeIn();
                        if ($(".post-grid__col:hidden").length < 9) {
                            $("#loadMore").fadeOut('slow');
                        }

                    });
                });

                $("a[href='#filter']").click(function () {
                    $("html, body").animate({
                        scrollTop: $('#filter').offset().top - 140
                    }, "slow");
                    return false;
                });

                $(window).scroll(function () {
                    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
                        $('.totop a').fadeIn();
                    } else {
                        $('.totop a').fadeOut();
                    }

                });
            });
        </script>
        <?php
            else :
                echo '<div class="post-grid__col col-12 mt-5 pt-5 no-results-found">
                <div class="post-card h-100 animate__animated animate__fadeInUp border-right-0">
                   <p class="display-4">No results found.</p>
                </div>


        </div>';
            endif;

    die();
}
```

---  page-insights.php with form filter and original query

Answer (score 0):

An update: the reason the newly published items weren’t showing after filter is that one or more of the filter taxonomies was empty. I have hide_empty=false on the filter drop downs , but is there a way to do that for the filtered response? — the current “solution” which is workable, is that there really shouldn’t be an empty taxonomy in this circumstance, so I should find a way to require them for publishing. there’s also some code here I took out in my build, for ex. localizing pagination script. Can’t get pagination to work in response presently. Otherwise, all is working as expected now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).